# asp net comparevalidator type double datatypecheck allows incorrect values

Tags: asp.net, validation, compare, double

ASP NET 4.0 on win 7

If I implement a CompareValidator like this:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmprValidatorDoubleType" ControlToValidate="TextBox10" Type="Double" Display="Dynamic" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="*Not a valid number." runat="server"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

It will accept values such as "5." (without the quotation marks) values without decimals. Is this a normal and expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is an expected behaviour, as you use the Attribute: ***[Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.operator.aspx)*** here, so firstly the values you enter into textBox will be tried converting implicitly into the `Type` you defined. i.e. `Double` here. So, I guess, `5.` gets converted to a double value successfully.

MSDN says this about ***[OPERATOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.operator.aspx)*** property of CompareValidator:

```
 A data type comparison of the value entered in the input control being validated and
 the data type specified by the BaseCompareValidator.Type property. Validation fails 
 if the value cannot be converted to the specified data
```

An integer is always ***[implicitly convertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx)*** to any of :  `long` , `float`, `double`, or `decimal`. This is because it is a conversion from smaller to larger data types and there is NO loss of data. See this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

Also, When you declare:

```
Double d = 5;
```

OR

```
Double d = Convert.ToDouble("5.");
```

Check the value of `d` in debugger. It displayed as: `5.0`.
So you can now guess that using 5 is actually interpreted as 5.0 and thus the validation passes.

Comment: yes but should this allow 5. I mean five plus the point? Shouldn't this be treated as a wrong or incomplete number?

Comment: No. It won't. Since your TYPE set in CompareValidator is : Double, so 5 is indeed considered a double as it gets implicitly converted to 5.0. This 5.0 is also a correct Double value.

Comment: You're right.  I've tried in MS VBA `CSng("5.")`.  It does get converted to a valid number.  Thanks and have a nice one!